# Swapping some digits of a number in c programming

Tags: c

I have a number that I wish to sort. I know how to sort it in ascending and descending order, but what the question wants is to switch places value in the number.

Comment: `int lcv; //initialize loop control variable` - this does not initialize a variable, it declares it

Comment: ahh youre right, good catch, thanks

Comment: Your logic will become unnecessarily complicated if you try and conditionally swap digits by manipulating an integer value itself, you are better served converting the number to its string representation, conditionally swapping middle or end characters and then converting the resulting string to int. Much much easier. (Hint - an integer can be no longer than 10 chars (11 with a preceding `'-'` sign), and if you use `sprintf` the conversion to string is simple. (don't forget to account for space for the *nul-terminating* character). Using `strtol` to go back is simple too.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned power(unsigned base, unsigned exp){
    unsigned result = 1;
    while(exp > 0){
        if(exp & 1)
            result = result * base;
        base = base * base;
        exp >>=1;
    }
    return result;//Overflow is not considered
}
int pow10(int exp){
    return power(10, exp);
}
int get_num_at(int n, int pos){
    int exp = pow10(pos);
    return n / exp % 10;//Changed by advice of chux
}
int swap(int n, int pos1, int pos2){
    if(pos1 == pos2)
        return n;
    int n1 = get_num_at(n, pos1);
    int n2 = get_num_at(n, pos2);
    return n - n1 * pow10(pos1) - n2 * pow10(pos2) + n1 * pow10(pos2) + n2 * pow10(pos1);
}
int length(int n){
    int len = 1;

    while(n /= 10)
        ++len;
    return len;
}
int arrange(int v){
    int len = length(v), half = len / 2;

    return (len & 1) ? swap(v, 0, len-1) : swap(v, half-1, half);//0 origin
}

int main (void) {
    int v;

    scanf("%d", &v);
    printf ("%d\n", arrange(v));
}
```

Comment: I think `return n / exp % 10;` is more overflow resilient than `return n % (exp * 10) / exp;`

Comment: @chux sure. I fixed according to chux recommendation. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment, to answer your question:

> *How would I modify the code below to get the above or do i have to start a new code?*

I would start with a new approach. Why? While you could use a set of *place-holders* and set various conditions to manipulate the integer values to accomplish a mid-digit or end-digit swap depending on odd/even, it is far easier to simply convert your integer value to a *string* and then manipulate the characters.

Given you are working with integers, the longest integer you will have to address is `INT_MIN` (`-2147483648`), or `11-chars` (`+1` for the *nul-terminating* character). You can simply use a static character buffer of `12` chars and call `sprintf` to convert you integer to a string (while getting its length in the same call). A simple odd/even test and you know to either swap the middle characters or the end characters. To convert the resulting string back to integer, simply use `strtol`.

You can test for a negative value at the beginning, handle the positive form, and then multiply the resulting value by `-1` for return if the value was negative. (**note:** you should also test for `INT_MIN` before assigning the positive form as `-INT_MIN` will not fit in an integer value. You must also check that the resulting integer after you swap digits will fit within an integer as well. -- that is left as an exercise for you).

Putting those pieces together, you can do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum {BASE = 10, MAXS = 12};            /* constants */

int minswap (int v)
{
    char buf[MAXS] = "";
    int neg = v < 0 ? -1 : 1,           /* flag negative numbers  */
        val = v * neg,                  /* handle as positive val */
        len = sprintf (buf, "%d", val); /* conver to str, get len */

    if (len % 2 == 0) {                 /* val is even */
        int m = len / 2;
        char tmp = buf[m - 1];          /* swap mid digits */
        buf[m - 1] = buf[m];
        buf[m] = tmp;
    }
    else {
        char tmp = *buf;                /* swap end digits */
        *buf = buf[len - 1];
        buf[len - 1] = tmp;
    }

    return (int)strtol (buf, NULL, BASE) * neg;
}

int main (void) {

    int v1 = 264802,
        v2 = 1357246;

    printf (" %d => %d\n", v1, minswap(v1));
    printf (" %d => %d\n", v2, minswap(v2));

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using your test values:

```
$ ./bin/minswap
 264802 => 268402
 1357246 => 6357241
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

---

**Without Library Function Usage**

If you have a requirement to no use any of the C-library functions in your `minswap` function, you can easily replace them with loops with something similar to the following:

```
enum {BASE = 10, MAXS = 12};            /* constants */

int minswap (int v)
{
    char buf[MAXS] = "";
    int neg = v < 0 ? -1 : 1,           /* flag negative numbers  */
        val = v * neg,                  /* handle as positive val */
        len = 0;

    while (len + 1 < MAXS && val) {     /* convert to string get len */
        buf[len++] = val % 10 + '0';
        val /= 10;
    }
    /* (you should validate len > 0 here) */

    if (len % 2 == 0) {                 /* val is even */
        int m = len / 2;
        char tmp = buf[m - 1];          /* swap mid digits */
        buf[m - 1] = buf[m];
        buf[m] = tmp;
    }
    else {
        char tmp = *buf;                /* swap end digits */
        *buf = buf[len - 1];
        buf[len - 1] = tmp;
    }

    while (len--)                       /* convert to int */
        val = val * 10 + buf[len] - '0';

    return val * neg;
}
```

(**note:** there is actually no need to convert to the character values with `-/+ '0'` since you are simply swapping the values at the mid or end positions, but for sake of completeness, that was included.)

Look things over and let me know if your have further questions.

Comment: but the thing is I cannot use the standard library. I am only allowed the loop control structures (do,while and for loops) and if else statements to complete the task. I am not allowed to use strings and arrays unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, just modify your loop to fill the buffer and you're good to go. You can go back to int simply.

Comment: I'll have a bit more time later in the morning. If you haven't been able to replace `sprintf` with your original loop to fill the buffer, and you second loop to convert the contents of the buffer back to int, I'll lend you another hand.

Comment: thank you for your help, looking at your code, ive started to get a rough idea on how to go about it, ill let you know in the morning thanks

Comment: If you get stuck, I've included the example. Good luck with your coding.

Comment: @skyblade1234 Post requirements like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125820/swapping-some-digits-of-a-number-in-c-programming#comment77224581_45126873) in the post rather than a comment.

Comment: Hey david, I have completed the code, its is a bit primitive, but it works but thank you for your help. If you want to look over my code, it is below.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. There is nothing you can't do it C with a couple of loops, string indexes and pointer arithmetic. It all boils down to accounting for each byte. (If it seems overwhelming, think about the question "How do you eat a whale?" -- answer "One bite (byte) at a time." `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without any standard library calls, arrays or strings, except for printing the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long shuffle(int v) {
    int i, n, x, d0, d1;
    long long p;

    /* compute the number of digits and the largest power of 10 <= v */
    for (x = v, p = 1, n = 1; x > 9; x /= 10, p *= 10, n++)
        continue;

    if (n & 1) {
        /* odd number of digits, swap first and last */
        d0 = v % 10;
        d1 = v / p;
        return d0 * p + v % p - d0 + d1;
    } else {
        /* even number of digits, swap middle 2 digits */
        for (i = 0, p = 1; i < n / 2 - 1; i++, p *= 10)
            continue;
        d0 = (v / p) % 10;
        d1 = (v / p) / 10 % 10;
        return v + p * (d0 - d1) * 9;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d => %lld\n", 0, shuffle(0));
    printf("%d => %lld\n", 1, shuffle(1));
    printf("%d => %lld\n", 42, shuffle(42));
    printf("%d => %lld\n", 24, shuffle(24));
    printf("%d => %lld\n", 264802, shuffle(264802));
    printf("%d => %lld\n", 1357246, shuffle(1357246));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 => 0
1 => 1
42 => 24
24 => 42
264802 => 268402
```

Notes:

- I do not handle negative numbers
- The reversed number might not fit in an `int`, so I used type `long long`, but on systems where `int` would have the same range as `long long`, you might still get an incorrect result.

Comment: [_I am not allowed to use strings and arrays unfortunately_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125820/swapping-some-digits-of-a-number-in-c-programming/45127889#comment77224581_45126873)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Hello again! I had not seen the OP's comment on David's post... answer updated with a simpler method.

Answer (score 0):

Ive completed the assignment and my code is as below. It is a bit primitive, but it works thank you all for your contribution.

```
int swapvalues(int input, int digit)
{
  int swapsort = 0; //initializes swapsort to 0
  int lastdigit; //finds he last digit of input
  int digits; //the total number of digits - 1
  int firstdigit; //finds the first digit of the input
  int middledigit; //finds the first middle digit in an even digit number
  int secondmiddledigit; //finds the second middle digit in an even digit number
  int firsthalf; //the first half of an even digit number
  int firsthalf2; //the second half of an even digit number
  int spacing; //the spacing between the output and the input
  if(digit % 2 != 0)
  {
    lastdigit  = input % 10;
    digits     = digit - 1;
    firstdigit = (int)(input / pow(10, digits));
    swapsort  = lastdigit;
    swapsort *= (int) pow(10, digits);
    swapsort += input % ((int)pow(10, digits));
    swapsort -= lastdigit;
    swapsort += firstdigit;
  }
  else
  {
    firsthalf = input / pow(10, (digit / 2));
    middledigit = firsthalf % 10;
    firsthalf2 = input / pow(10, (digit / 2) - 1);
    secondmiddledigit = firsthalf2 % 10;
    spacing = (((secondmiddledigit * 10) + (middledigit)) - ((middledigit * 10) + (secondmiddledigit))) * pow(10, ((digit / 2) - 1));
    swapsort = input + spacing;
  }
  return(swapsort);
}
```